# Google NDB Model syntax

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have an example line of code for `google ndb model` (datastore)

```
V=model.Video.query(model.Video.key==key).get()
```

Assuming that the '`key`' has a value, is the instantiation lines below feasible/valid or syntactically correct ?

```
+ (Video)key.get()
+ V = model.Video(key)
```

Not sure if they would work. Thanks for your inputs

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the (valid) entity key you don't need a query to get the entity, you can simply get it by key lookup:

```
V = key.get()
```